# RAMDisk disappears after random read tests

Tags: centos, modprobe, ramdisk, fio

I have created 60GB RAMDisk using the command `modprobe brd rd_size=62914560`. It creates 16 RAMDisks and I use /dev/ram1. The linux is CentOS 7.5 with kernel version 3.10. I don't make any filesystems on RAMDisk because I want to use it as a raw block device.

My test scenario includes two phases and I use FIO tool:

(1) I write sequentially to /dev/ram1 so that it is initialized and the memory is allocated it.

(2) I test the RAMDisk performance with 4KB random read.

However, the RAMDisk disappears during the random read test (second phase). I have checked this issue using the command `free -m`. Why RAMDisk disappears when we read from it?

Comment: Can check `dmesg` for anything that might look suspicious and how much total RAM do you have in that machine? (PS: when mentioning `fio` in a question it is helpful for the reader to see the full `fio` command line/jobfile that you used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug of CentOS 7. There is no issue in CentOS 8.